# duplicate traffic on server

Tags: groovy, beanshell, network-traffic

I have real live data of http requests made to my server. I want to duplicate those requests with their real timestamps.

i'm reading/parsing my requests and their timestamps from a csv file. I have about a million requests and I want to test how many requests my server can handle before it crashes.

I've been doing some reading and it seems best thing is to use is either Beanshell or Groovy.
My problem is i'm not really sure on how to use them with a custom timer for the requests I send. I want to read timestamps from the csv, calculate the delay between each request and send the requests based on that delay.

any thoughts? .. or if someone has a better way to do this whole thing, it would also be of help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as a huge overhead where you just need to find the peak of transactions or concurrent users,

Or/and find transaction per second rate and then execute the "duplication" according these parameters.